# Why does 1 programatically defined ImageView change multiple ImageViews defined in XML?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, alpha

Here is my situation.
I defined a xml file with 2 table layouts each having 1 table row and each row having 3 relative layout, each relative layout has 3 image views.

I want to  lower the alpha on all image views of 1 relative layout when i click on it, so i use this piece of code:

```
for(int i = 0;i<randStupac.getChildCount();i++)   
        {
            ImageView image =(ImageView)randStupac.getChildAt(i);
            image.setAlpha(100);
        }
```

randStupac is a relative layout with 3 imageViews, but for some reason this changes not only those 3 ImageViews, but also randomly other Images from other relative layouts, and i dont want that.

i checked with logcat that the childcount is 3.

So this means that in 3 iteration there are not 3, but a random number above 3 of ImageViews changed.

So can ony1 plz help me to only change the images i need to change?

here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TableLayoutTijelo">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/TableRowTijelo">
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacTijelo1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickTijelo">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo1" android:src="@drawable/tresnja"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo1" android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo4" android:src="@drawable/tresnja"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo4"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo7" android:src="@drawable/tresnja"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacTijelo2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickTijelo">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo2"
                    android:src="@drawable/jabuka"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo2" android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo5" android:src="@drawable/lubenica"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo5"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo8" android:src="@drawable/tresnja"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacTijelo3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickTijelo">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo3" android:src="@drawable/lubenica"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo3"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo6" android:src="@drawable/ribizli"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaTijelo6"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaTijelo9" android:src="@drawable/lubenica"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/brojacBod"
            android:text="9999999" android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="9999999"
            android:id="@+id/brojacPokusaj" android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"></TextView>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TableLayoutRandom">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/TableRowRandom">
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacRandom1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickRandom">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom1"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom1" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom4"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom4" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom7"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacRandom2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickRandom">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom2" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom2" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom5"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom5" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom8"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacRandom3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickRandom">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom3"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom3" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom6"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SlikaRandom6" android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom9"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
     android:id="@+id/comboDouble"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" android:id="@+id/comboMulti"></ImageView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ReklamaIgra">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the "on click" function:;

```
    public void clickRandom(final View view)
{
    if(odabrano == true)
    {
        switch(stupacRandom)
        {
            case 1:randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom1);break;
            case 2:randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom2);break;
            case 3:randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom3);break;
        }
        randStupac.startAnimation(animacijaDeselect);
        for(int i = 0;i<randStupac.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            ImageView slika1 =(ImageView)randStupac.getChildAt(i);
            slika1.setAlpha(puno);
        }
    }
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.StupacRandom1 :
        {
            stupacRandom = 1;
            randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom1);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.StupacRandom2 :
        {
            stupacRandom = 2;
            randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom2);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.StupacRandom3 :
        {
            stupacRandom = 3;
            randStupac = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.StupacRandom3);
            break;
        }
    }
```

i declare RelativeLayout randStupac for whole class, u know, before i write the functions.

Sorry that the words i wrote are in Croatian

Comment: post your layout.xml file and code where you initialize the randStupac variable.

Answer (score 0):

remove all your code and add this

```
public void clickRandom(final View view) {
    for(int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ImageView slika1 = (ImageView) view.getChildAt(i);
        slika1.setAlpha(100);
    }
}
```

or you can use the same id (I mean, imageView1, imageView2 and imageView3) for all ImagesViews

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/StupacRandom3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="clickRandom">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom6" />
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:id="@+id/SlikaRandom9" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and write something like this

```
public void clickRandom(final View view) {
    ImageView slika1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    slika1.setAlpha(100);
    ImageView slika2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    slika2.setAlpha(100);
    ImageView slika3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    slika3.setAlpha(100);
}
```

Comment: i dont understand why should i remove my code, i dont see the difference in your first example and my first example, and i cant give then all same ID because of other reasons

Comment: ok, i see the diference, but there are no getChildCount() and getChildAt() for the View objekt

Comment: you can cast the view to a ViewGroup: ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;

Comment: i did what u said, but no use, it still changes images randomly in addition to those it is supposed to change

Comment: well, i give up, idk if there is a bug in the SDK or something and i dont want to select every picture by name, i  simply change the background collor of the relative layout and problem solved